# Click and Drag a gameobject in a Overlay Canvas in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Canvas setup and it is in Screen Space - Overlay and I almost have what I am looking for but the results are just a little bit off.  By a little bit off I mean when I click and hold to drag something from my inventory it isn't exactly where the mouse is but it is close.  Now the dragging doesn't work but when I am done dragging my GameObject returns to its respective place correctly.

My Code :

```
void Awake(){
    rectTrans = GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
}

void Start(){
    localRectTrans = rectTrans.localPosition;
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data){
    // IF we are dragging an item
    if(itemBeingDragged != null){
        itemBeingDragged = null;
        // return this gameobject to its original location.
        rectTrans.localPosition = localRectTrans;
    }
}

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData data){
    // IF we have an item to drag.
    if(isItem){
        // Set the itemBeingDragged to this gameobject.
        itemBeingDragged = gameObject;
        // Get the starting mouse location for dragging.
        startMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    }
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data){
    // IF we have an item to drag in this inventory slot.
    if(isItem){
        // Get the location of the mouse.
        Vector2 curMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        // Get the difference in position from when the mouse was first clicked to where it is currently being dragged.
        Vector2 diffInPos = curMousePosition - startMousePos;
        // The current position based on the difference in position with the mouse and the local position of this inventory slot.
        Vector2 curPos = localRectTrans + diffInPos;
        transform.localPosition = curPos;
    }
}
```

How can I get this to actually be exactly where my mouse cursor is?  I feel I am so close but just keep drawing a blank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle`.

```
public Canvas parentCanvasOfImageToMove;
public Image imageToMove;   

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
{
    Vector2 pos;
    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(parentCanvasOfImageToMove.transform as RectTransform, data.position, parentCanvasOfImageToMove.worldCamera, out pos);
    imageToMove.transform.position = parentCanvasOfImageToMove.transform.TransformPoint(pos);
}
```

**OR**

```
public Canvas parentCanvasOfImageToMove;
public Image imageToMove; 

public void Update()
{
    Vector2 pos;
    RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(parentCanvasOfImageToMove.transform as RectTransform, Input.mousePosition, parentCanvasOfImageToMove.worldCamera, out pos);
    imageToMove.transform.position = parentCanvasOfImageToMove.transform.TransformPoint(pos);
}
```

To Smooth the movement simply replace

```
imageToMove.transform.position = parentCanvasOfImageToMove.transform.TransformPoint(pos);
```

with

```
imageToMove.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(imageToMove.transform.position, parentCanvasOfImageToMove.transform.TransformPoint(pos), Time.deltaTime * 30f);
```

Comment: Hey Programmer, I appreciate the help but I am still getting an error.  The above code I used and I have a GIF to look at here : http://imgur.com/ED6YKU8 .  I think I needed to clarify more and say that the rectTrans is my inventory slot, here is my current heirarchy : http://clip2net.com/s/3y4J6bo .  I also tried using the first parameter in the code you linked to be my canvas's RectTransform and this is what it looks like in a GIF : http://imgur.com/2EeoTlf . Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @JoeyL You left some info out so I did some guessing work. Please align the rect transform of **Inventory Slot 1** to Bottom Left like this http://i.imgur.com/2AGytrc.png. Test it. If it doesn't work, undo it then align the rect transform of **Inventory Bag** to Bottom Left. If it doesn't work, undo it again and then align the rect transform of **Inventory** to Bottom Left. If it fails, report back. I got another solution.

Comment: @JoeyL If what I said above fail, try `yourInventory.localPosition = pos;` instead of  `rectTrans.anchoredPosition = pos;`  pos is the position from the code in my answer. Let me know if any of these work for you.

Comment: Will do, trying this out now.

Comment: The first parameter of ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle should be the Canvas RectTransform right?

Comment: @JoeyL yes. use the transform of the object you are dragging.

Comment: @JoeyL I decided to test it myself and I made some changes. Look at the new code. This worked on my side.

Comment: The second part of the code worked! Thank you so much!  I can't tell you how much time I have spent trying to understand what I was doing wrong and following that code I have a better idea how to handle this kind of stuff in the future.  Also I made you this : http://imgur.com/r0HgpzP

Comment: @JoeyL Lol thanks for that picture. I decided to test it before posting. The first one should actually work if you attach the script to the canvas. If you don't attach it to the Canvas, the Drag call back function wont work. Maybe that's the problem you have. The second one will work in all cases. Glad one of them worked for you. Happy coding!

Comment: For screen space overlay, I get very small values, between 1 and 10 for 1080 p resolution

Comment: The camera parameter should be null if canvas is screen space overlay, otherwise you get incorrect results like I had above this comment